# Culebra stuck with "Touching Point (units=DIP)"

Tags: python, android, python-imaging-library, androidviewclient

I am trying to create tests on a device using Culebra.

I gave the command

```
>python culebra -uUG -P 0.25 -o myscript.py
Exception AttributeError: "'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'" in <bound method PhotoImage.__del__ of <PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage object at 0x04CCB930>> ignored
```

The GUI is stuck with a green prompt on the top with the text "Touching point (units=DIP)". The screen has become translucent and no touches are accepted anymore.

I think the GUI being stuck is related to the exception mentioned earlier. I had used the command `pip install pillow`. Could this be due to a wrong version of `pillow`? I don't know what to do now.

Any help is appreciated.

---

Environment information:

- Culebra version : culebra 20.0.0b4
- Python version : Python 2.7.12
- venv : No virtual environment used

Comment: Can you please add the python version, culebra version, virtual env, etc. used?

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano Hello. I have added the environment details. Please do let me know if any other information is required.

Comment: Is a venv required? @DiegoTorresMilano

Comment: No, just asking

Comment: I mentioned the virtual environment as it might be easier to test other version (i.e. python 3.7). Also a screenshot might help to see the overall state.

Comment: Btw, I tested pyenv + python3.7 + androidviewclient  20.0.0b4 + Pillow 7.0.0 and didn't find any issue.

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano I'll try with Python 3.7 too and will update with results.